# Converting binary decision diagram to truth table

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, implementation, boolean-logic, binary-decision-diagram

Given a binary decision diagram, how do I convert it into a truth table?  What is the exact algorithm for it ? I have been trying this for a long time. Here is an example which one can follow:

[image]

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BDD.png).

(The dotted edges represent 0; solid edges, 1.)

Comment: maybe turn a full path decision into a bitmap and fill the value into a pre-allocated table?

Comment: Please elaborate ...

Comment: i don't quite understand what you are trying to do, and i think the others don't too. maybe you can offer a precise example, what's the input, what's the output, and what's the data format. after that, i can try to answer your question.

Comment: If your BDD looks like that (no "skipped" variables), it's completely trivial (just trace all the paths). If you do have "skipped" variables (dont-cares), you have to be careful with them, especially when going to a sink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginning at the root node, traverse tree in depth-first manner.

For each leaf node reached, record an entry in truth table as follows:

- `x1` is 0 if you descended the dashed edge from node `x1`; 1 otherwise.
- `x2` is 0 if you descended the dashed edge from node `x2`; 1 otherwise.
- `x3` is 0 if you descended the dashed edge from node `x3`; 1 otherwise.
- `f` is value of the leaf node.